# Joption pane location relative to its parent

Tags: java, swing, location, joptionpane

I have a JOptionPane that checks for confirmation when a it's parent(JPanel) is closed.The problem is that when the parent is minimized and I close it from the start bar the confirmation Dialog is shown on the top left side of the screen not centered on the screen as it does when the parent is maximized.I assume that it gets its location based on it's parent,can there be some other reason for this and what fixes do you recommend?  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's a problem of JOptionPane which does not support this case. I would suggest to restore the main window before and then show the option pane (ok, it's a workaround).

Comment: How should I restore it in order to keep it's initial location?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try `Window.toFront()` method

Comment: `How should I restore it` - Frame.setState(Frame.NORMAL)